# Bootsrap Navbar toggles quickly in mobile view

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

My **bootstrap** navbar toggles too soon in **mobile view**. I want it to toggle i.e display and hide links on clicking the hamburger toggle button. Initially I thought it's due to margin on body or my divs but my problem still persists. I am unable to figure out what is causing this issue. Is there a way to achieve this using bootstrap. Is some styling (margin etc.) causing this issue, or will it have to done using custom javascript function to toggle links using button click event?
Thank You.

Comment: Please read  [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/754119). For more details read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: Yes, I have hence, edited the question removing the link, pardon me, I typed the question in haste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bootstrap CSS version you used is ver4.3.1 but the bootstrap JS you used is ver3.3.7. Update the JS to the compatible version and it will work as expected. You should place the CSS script path before the JS script path.

```
<!--   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"> </script> -->
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

FYI, the latest version of the bootstrap is ver4.5.0. You may update to the following version.

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```